# clipToBounds with value false is not supported on Android. You can use this.android.getParent().setClipChildren(false) as an alternative

Tags: android, user-interface, debugging, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

clipToBounds is not working in android and getting this warning clipToBounds with value false is not supported on Android. You can use this.android.getParent().setClipChildren(false) as an alternative

I tried to replace clipToBounds with setClipChildren with true but it did not work

```
<AbsoluteLayout
verticalAlignment="bottom"
ios:clipToBounds="false"
class="main-wrapper"
shadow="50">
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

the expected result should be like the parent component should allow its child component to overflow on top of the parent component

Comment: Can you show us how exactly you tried `setClipChildren(..)`, what you mean by it did not work? It didn't give expected output Or it threw any error?

Comment: I replace clipToBounds="false" (clipToBounds works fine only on ios) with setClipChildren="false" or true but it did not allow the parent component to overflow its children,  please take a look at this video I'm using the same approach it works for Ios but not for Android. if we use clipToBounds="false" in android there is a warning (You can use this.android.getParent().setClipChildren(false) as an alternative
Ask Question) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmUF6nxY7vk

Comment: That doesn't what the log meant, you had to call `setClipChildren` method on the parent element of the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `setClipChildren` method on the parent view, something like

**HTML**

```
<AbsoluteLayout
verticalAlignment="bottom"
ios:clipToBounds="false"
class="main-wrapper"
shadow="50"
(loaded)="onLoaded($event)">
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**TS**

```
onLoaded(event) {
  const layout = event.object;
  if (layout.android) {
    layout.android.getParent().setClipChildren(false);
  }
}
```